# How to turn off the screen without sleep on a MacBook Pro with Touch Bar?

Tags: macos, screen, touch-bar

Is there any shortcut for it?

I tried <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Touch ID</kbd>, which didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

## There are two methods I will explain.

### 1. Use the 'Lock display' touch bar shortcut

In System Preferences -> Keyboard settings, click 'Customise Touch Bar'. There is a shortcut 'Screen Lock' which you can use to lock the display, as well as 'Sleep' and 'Screen Saver' shortcuts which have their own respective functions.

### 2. Leave computer open, but screen turned off

If you need to turn off the display, without actually sending the computer to sleep, simply turn the brightness down to the minimum.
On an MacBook Pro (Touch Bar) leave brightness at lowest (with slider as left as it can go)
<sub>If you're comfortable with the terminal, try `$ caffeinate -dimsu -p <process-id>` for leaving a long process running without sleeping computer, where `<process-id>` is the PID for the process (you can look this up in Activity Monitor)</sub>

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a legitimate answer which answers the question with experience.

Comment: I upvote you @Benj, your answer is actually even better than the one with 170+ upvotes, as I enabled F1 to F12 on the stupid touch bar.